# How can I enter tomorrow's date into a text field using Java and Selenium2/Webdriver

Tags: java, date, textbox, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am writing an automated test in Java using Selenium2/WebDriver.  I need to validate a birthday in the future is not allowed.  To get tomorrow's date, I am using:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date today = calendar.getTime();
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
```

I am having trouble printing that to a text field, since .sendKeys requires characters.  Any help is appreciated.  I'm also unsure if that is the best way to get tomorrow's date.

Comment: this code should work and is simply fine imo, what is your problem? post code of your problem please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is basically right. Use a `Calendar` to produce `Date` objects:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date today = calendar.getTime();

calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
Date tomorrow = calendar.getTime();
```

Use `SimpleDateFormat` to format the `Date` as a `String`:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

String todayAsString = dateFormat.format(today);
String tomorrowAsString = dateFormat.format(tomorrow);

System.out.println(todayAsString);
System.out.println(tomorrowAsString);
```

Prints:

```
09-Aug-2012
10-Aug-2012
```

You can use Selenium to send those `String` objects to the date control (if it accepts keyed input, of course). You'll need to adjust the date pattern `"dd-MMM-yyyy"` to match the format expected by the input control on the page, e.g. perhaps it's (`"MM/dd/YY"`)?

Answer (score 0):

First, don't you mean to add before defining the date? Then, you could do a

```
today.toString()
```

to assign via sendkeys, but IMO you should look first at the format the widget accepts (e.g. european vs US) and format your date accordingly (e.g. using something like [this](http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/)).